# Delete from CrudRepository doesnt work on child object

Tags: spring, rest, jpa

I have a DELETE method in my RestController that needs to delete CartItem object from Cart.They are mapped with OneToMany relationship and after calling delete method from CrudRepository the item stays in the database and i don't get any errors...

I tried to remove CascadeType.ALL to CascadeType.REMOVE , tried to get a cart from a Principal object also and also tryed deleteById(Long id) and delete(CartItem cartItem) and nothing helped , item is still in the database.

```
//CartItem repository

public interface CartItemRepository extends CrudRepository<CartItem, Long> {

    CartItem getByCartItemId(Long id);

}

//Cart entity

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<CartItem> cartItems = new HashSet<>();

//CartItem entity

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
 @JsonIgnore
 private Cart cart;

//Rest method

 @RequestMapping(value = "remove/{cartItemId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
 public void removeItemFromCart(@PathVariable (value = "cartItemId") Long 
 cartItemId){
        cartItemRepository.deleteById(cartItemId);
  }
```

Comment: Probably a problem because you don´t synchronize your bidirectional relationship. If you delete a child entity of a child owning bidirectional relationship you have to ensure that it is removed from the collection on the onetomany side. For more details read this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `orphanRemoval=true` option to yours `@OneToMany` annotation

Comment: How yours `deleteById` looks like, do you execute in a transaction?

Comment: Its built in method from CrudRepository ,tried @Transactional but didn't helped..